# How to read file line by line and send response to ajax request using java and ajax with jsonp?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to read file line by line that is on different domain and send response to ajax request as each line is read.

I have written code that reads file and send last line as response.

Here is my jquery-ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
 url: 'http://192.168.xx.xx:8080/myproject/readFile',
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 jsonp: 'callback',
 jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse',
 success: function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    },
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log("ok");
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
  }
});
```

Here is my servlet code:

```
public class readFile extends HttpServlet{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException{
    // The name of the file to open.
    System.out.println("in read file");
    String fileName = "myfile,txt";
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        BasicDBObject oneLine = new BasicDBObject();
        String set_data = "";
        StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            line = line.replaceAll("\\{","");
            line = line.replaceAll("\\}","");
            line = line.replaceAll("\\*","");
            line = line.replaceAll("\\:","");
            line = line.replaceAll("\\|","");
           // stringBuilder.append(line);

         }  
  /* out.println("parseResponse("+JSON.parse("{'Name':'"+stringBuilder.toString()+"'}")+")");*/
        out.flush();
   out.println("parseResponse("+JSON.parse("{'Name':'"+line+"'}")+")");
    out.flush(); 
        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");      
    }

}
public void set_print(String name){

}

}
```

This code read file and give me output last line of file on each request.
But I want to read all contents of file as single line at a time.

How do I read a file line by line and send response to ajax request??

Comment: You can't have multiple response for single request. `doGet` have single response with single request.

Comment: If I use setinterval to call read file, will it work??

Comment: Yes, then it will work. You can read specified line number on BufferedReader.

Comment: I have implemented the same but it reads last line only  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    out.print("parseResponse("+JSON.parse("{'Name':'");
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        line = line.replaceAll("\\{","");
        line = line.replaceAll("\\}","");
        line = line.replaceAll("\\*","");
        line = line.replaceAll("\\:","");
        line = line.replaceAll("\\|","");
        out.print(line);
     }  
     out.print("'}")+")");
     out.flash();
```

Answer (score 0):

"But I want to read all contents of file as single line at a time."

Do you want to read the whole file to a string ?if yes ,then use Apache Commons FileUtils

it has methods like :

```
static String readFileToString(File file); // Reads the contents of a file into a String using the default encoding for the VM.
static String readFileToString(File file, String encoding); //Reads the contents of a file into a String.
```

[Apache Commons IO Docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)